# Any limitation for Amazon Product Ads API "ItemLookup"?

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-web-api, amazon-product-advertising-api

Currently Amazon Product Ads API has the limitation of 10 pages for ItemSearch requests, so one can get 100 items at most. I wonder, does ItemLookup has a similar limitation? If I **already have** 10 000 or 100 000 item ids, will I be able to request the information (shipping weight, seller rank, other details...) for all of them **without any issue** via the API ?

The question:

I can send 10 000 (100 000) requests one by one and **there's no limitation in the API about it**, right?